# How to write a javaScript function to enter 2 numbers through prompts and display the sum of those numbers in an alert?

Tags: javascript, input, prompt

I wanted to display this:
Enter your numbers:
1st :
2nd :
Answer :
I tried doing this:

```
var a = prompt("A : ", "");
var b = prompt("B : ", "");
function calc(a,b)
{
   return a + b;
}
alert ("The addition is =" + calc(a,b);
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with only one prompt:

```
var numbers = prompt("Enter two numbers separated by a semi-colon: ", "");
var a = numbers.split(";")[0];
var b = numbers.split(";")[1];

function calc(a,b)
{
   return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
}
alert ("The addition of " + numbers + " is = " + calc(a,b));
```

Comment: However if I try to add numbers like 0.3 and 0.9 that is decimals. it displays a vague answer

Comment: The chosen solution cannot calculate decimals either

Comment: answer amended to calculate decimals

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse the return from the prompts

```js
var a = prompt("A : ", "");
var b = prompt("B : ", "");
function calc(a,b)
{
   return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
}
alert ("The addition is =" + calc(a,b));
```

Comment: It does not evaluate deciamals